# Is anyone aware if window.URL.createObjectURL is no longer working?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, blob

I have an LWC which takes the content of a QR Code in my clipboard and does some magic on it to read the content.

In my Sandbox, which is on API V60.0, it seems to be working perfectly fine, but in Prod, which is on API V59.0, it throws an error.

I've had a look at the Applications tab of the Chrome Dev Tools and in the Sandbox I can see that the Blob is being loaded correctly:

[image]

But in Prod I am getting this:

[image]

Comment: I usually like to blame Locker Security for this. Have you tried to [Enable Lightning Web Security in an Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-enable.html) in production to see if that changes things?

Comment: Yes that's it! I just disabled it in Prod and it worked -_- I never thought of checking that.

Comment: Be aware that LWS is the future, so disabling it is not a long term solution.

Comment: It looks like LWS should support this, I wonder if there's another bug, again... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/lws-distortion-viewer#URL_createObjectURL-value

Case submitted, we'll see what happens